# Linking outer Control Field to the inner field and MU calculation

Tags: ingress

If we have 2 control fields within each other and after the 2 fields are created we connect the outer CF to the Inner CF do we still get MU points for the 2 original CFs and the last 2 CF points after the connection is made?

Answer (score 2):

You only get MU points for the two narrow triangles between the inner and outer fields.